# E-mail server - my emails are sent properly to gmail, but nowhere else

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, email-server

Few days ago I have installed Hmail on my server, with pretty default config. Today i saw, that this e-mail server is not working for my local e-mail account providers (my country's local yahoo versions etc), emails sent by my server are only properly received by gmail. Is there anything additional that i need to setup on my email server in order to send e-mails, so they can be properly received everywhere?

**Edit:** I just found out that my emails were sent, but rejected due to anti-spam. What can I do about it?

Comment: Does your ISP provide you with a static IP address? (FWIW, I used Hmailserver for years and found it to be very easy to configure and extremely reliable.)

Comment: @GordThompson: Edited my post, I just found out that those email acc providers are rejecting my e-mails as a spam, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Is your public IP address for that server static, or dynamic?

Comment: Have you checked to see if your WAN IP is listed on any RBLs? If it's a dynamic IP or a standard broadband service then it almost certainly will be.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dynamic external (WAN) IP address then you'll need to configure your mail server to send all outgoing messages through your ISP's "official" SMTP server. Many people refer to this as using a "smarthost", but the hMailServer documentation calls it an "SMTP Relayer". See [this page](http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.4/?page=reference_protocolsmtp) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reverse DNS/PTR record. Contact your ISP.

Gmail does not need a reverse DNS entry from sending email servers. Yahoo, Juno, AOL, and others do require it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to contact the specific site mail administrators to get more information as to why you are rejected.  If it a blacklist, you'll definitely have to contact them in any event.  On a blacklisting, the only path to restitution is through the site mail administrator.